# iOS Comparing two objects to see if they overlapped in time event

Tags: ios

Let's say object MEvent , it has two fields

```
     NSDate *start_time;
     NSDate *end_time;
```

event1, event2 are instances of MEvent object, How to find out the two instances have overlapping in time?

What's the easiest implementation for that?

Answer (score 2):

Compare starTime and endTime of different instances. If startTime is later than the other instance's endTime, it means there is no overlap. You have to do the comparison both ways.

If it passes above check, it means there is overlap.

Comment: I assume startTime and endTime is in order within an instance.

Comment: OK, a bit more challenges, let say I have event, event2, ...event100,  to find how many of them overlapped and those overlapped would into same arrays and you probably would end up with many arrays.

Comment: I am not entirely sure of the outcome you want, but it definitely requires different algorithm. I think you have to create a union of time range when you compare two instances and compare next object with the yielded time range and create another union...